# Who to contact to understand my credit score?

Tags: credit, debt

When I was a kid, all the way until I was about 18, I was very ill. I would often have to go to the doctor or hospital and get treatments and scanned, etc.

I have multiple debts that occurred when I was below the age of 18, and two of them are appearing as negative marks on Credit Karma. Interestingly enough, these two (the ones incurred when I was below the age of 18) are only showing up for TransUnion, not equifax.

There is only one showing up where I was above the age of 18, and it is for 143 dollar.

It was evidently sent to collections in June, 2015. So, this is quite an old debt.

The company that I incurred the debt from is a doctor's office that I used to go to, and the collecting agency is Transworld Systems.

Do I contact the doctor's office, or Transworld Systems, or the Credit Bureau?

I first called Transworld Systems and stupidly gave the girl my SSN, and also filed for a dispute on the claim.

Any help, guys?

I really don't know where to even begin.

Comment: "I have multiple debts that occurred when I was below the age of 18" In my jurisdiction I'm pretty sure minors can't accrue debts. Are you sure these debts are yours personally, not an insurers?